# View secondary GET requests in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

If making a request to a specific URL generates multiple other GET requests (embedded videos etc.), visible in the Network tab of Developer Tools, how would you locate those requests and make them visible in Python?

```
import requests 
url = "https://learning.oreilly.com/videos/learn-javascript/9780136752899/9780136752899-LJS1_01_01_02"
r = requests.get(url)
# then somehow return whatever is visible in the network tab.
```

I'm trying to print these two GET requests[image: these two requests] in Python instead of manually using Dev Tools each time.

Comment: If those requests are triggered by Javascript: not really. You'd need a headless browser which evaluates that Javascript. `requests` can't do much with that.

Comment: Is there a particular headless browser you'd recommend?